# Moving one harddrive between laptops will windows 10 work?

Tags: windows-10

So I have a new laptop form work. But my older laptop has a better/bigger ssd. And has all my stuff nicely configured.
Hardware wise they are both Asus with a Intel processors and Nvidia Graphics cards.

If I just put the ssd in the new laptop will Windows 10 work?
Or will it start complaining about license stuff? I understand I probably need to update my drivers.

**Edit**
I've moved the harddrive and Windows did do a whole device reconfiguration. It downloaded a few driver updates on it's own. And everything works.
Windows isn't complaining.... Yet..... If it does start complaining I'll edit again.

Comment: Windows will probably start complaining about activation.  It really seems like it would be worth your time and effort to migrate your personal files and folders to the "new" hard drive.  I know that it's time consuming, but the end result is more more reliable.

Comment: The time is one aspect. But also the older SSD is bigger. So that's also a plus

Comment: Understood.  The comment below from Frank Thomas is exactly right, though:  contrary to what the posted answer says, unless the hardware is absolutely identical you are definitely going to encounter an activation error problem.  The bottom line is that Windows is smart enough to know that that hard drive is now residing in a different computer, and technically your work-issued laptop isn't legally authorized to run your licensed copy of Windows 10 from another computer.

Comment: Based upon your latest edit, I would ensure that Windows 10 is activated.  If it isn't activated it won't complain right away, but it will eventually:  [How to Check if Windows 10 is Activated](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/20779-activation-windows-10-check.html)

Answer (score 0):

It will work, just transplant the hard drive. However, if you have windows 10 on the new laptop's SSD and not on your old laptop's SSD, then you won't be able to achieve your goal.

It won't complain about licensing issues as long as the windows 10 on your old SSD is registered.

Comment: The caveat here is that this is only GUARANTEED to work if the hardware is identical on both systems. In this case they are close enough to make it likely that the new disk will work. I'm not sure about the internals of Win10 activation as I was with prior versions, but in older windows OSes, a new motherboard (or new NIC suprisingly) will require reactivation for OEM distributed media.

Comment: Even if you have to call, I'm told you can insist and get them to authorize activation. Just say you are swapping the OS's between the two PCs, so they have a note that the person you are talking to can justify doing so..